# Check if Selenium Element contains text in one class then print text of other class

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I am trying to loop a table in Python and Selenium.

I have a site looking like this:

```
<td class="td3">
    <div class="bla">
        <span class="label">User:</span>
    <div class="text">
</td>
```

I need to check if the *bla class* contains "User:"

If so I want to print the text from the *class text* with some string in front of it.

If it does not contain it I want to print it with nothing in front of it.

Is something like this even possible? It tried get attribute and some other things but cant get it to work :/

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Beautiful Soup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/), which is a great Python library for parsing html.  The following code parses the html and returns the text inside the 'bla' class.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<td class="td3">
    <div class="bla">
        <span class="label">User:</span>
    <div class="text">
    </td>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# if you know for sure that there is only one instance of the class, 
# you can use soup.find(...) which returns a single value instead of a list

blaList = soup.findAll(attrs={'class' : 'bla'})
for item in blaList:
    if 'User:' in item.text:
        # {your code printing the text...}
```

To get the html, you can use selenium as referenced [here](https://pythonbasics.org/selenium-get-html/). For example, the following code returns the entire html source of a page.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org")
html = browser.page_source
```

You could also get the html content of an element by using the innerHTML attribute below or the source of the element with outerHTML.  (more info [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/get-html-source-of-webelement-in-selenium-webdriver-using-python))

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h4")    
element.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done but the sample code below may or may not work because of the small sampling of HTML provided in the question. It should at least get you pointed in the right direction.

Steps:
Grab the TD and look for the two child elements. Based on the content of these two elements, add specific strings to the `output` variable and then print it.

The code:

```
cells = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("td.td3")
for row in cells:
    output = ""
    label = row.find_element_by_css_selector("div.bla > span.label").text
    text = row.find_element_by_css_selector("div.text").text
    if label == "User:":
        output = "some string: "
    output += text
    print(output)
```